# Php redirect to one server to another sever php page

Tags: php, javascript

I have two server A and B and both server are same script but i want redirect page when i login to server A login page then the page is automatic redirect to server B login page is it possible?

Comment: What about the domains, are they in a shared hosting...

Comment: are you referring into logging in to two websites at the same time? or is just just normal redirection?

Comment: No actually i have 2 seprate server A and B and both are same page i want to redirct when i login server A the page automatic redirect to Server B login page

Answer (score 0):

use header function available in php

```
$server_url='http://url-for-server-B';
header('Location: '.$server_url);
```

Comment: plz can you expalin me brief?

Comment: @kunalwani Please read the documentation on the [Location header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourlogincode ="SELECT WHATEVER FROM WHATEVER"; // do not forget to add your database type in here for example `mysql_query` 

if ($yourlogincode) 
{
//add your session code here
yourloginpagefromsiteB = "";
header('Location: '.$yourloginpagefromsiteB);
exit();
}
else
{
exit();
}
```

Comment: you should fix the quotes of `header`

Comment: hey its not working actually i have 2 sever when i login server one login page they automatic redirect to server two login page...

Comment: that is why I asked you in the comment section about how do you want it to redirect and you told me you just want to redirect it two the server two login page. The code that I gave you should work with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide a bit more information.  But, let me see if I can run through some scenarios.

First, let's assume that you login on either server, and you want it to goto an authenticated realm after login.  This means you have to find a way to share the session between the two servers.  You might consider creating the session store in a database that both servers can access.  You'll still have to pass the session token from server A to server B after login.

Otherwise, if you're saying both servers are on the same domain, but each is a subdomain, you can choose to have your session cookie have a domain of the base domain - and all subdomains can access that session then.  Still, the session data would either need to be stored in a database both servers had access to - ooorrr - mount a directory that both servers had access to.

Finally, if you want the user to login on either server A or B - but don't care about the authentication after you reach server B, then the solutions the other people provided will help.

My guess is you're trying to do some sort of single sign-on, so check into sharing your session among the servers.  Please provide more information if you'd like a more pin-point answer.